# Is this hitting probability counter-intuitive?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let the homogeneous Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be described by the following graph:

> [image]

Then the only missing arrow is from $0$ to $0$ with $\mathbb P\left(X_{1}=0 | X_{0}=0\right)= 1-3/5-1/5 = 1/5$.

Let $h_i$ be the probability of starting from $i$ and hitting $3$. Then I have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{aligned}
h_0 &=  \frac{1}{5} h_0  + \frac{3}{5} h_1\\
h_1 &=  1h_2\\
h_2 &=  \frac{1}{3} h_1  + \frac{2}{3} h_3\\
h_3 &=  1
\end{aligned}$$

Thus $h_1=h_2=h_3 =1$ and $h_0 = 3/4$.

To me, $h_1 =1$ is quite counter-intuitive because we can go from $1$ to $2$ and vice versa all the time with probability $1/3$. Hence there may be some chance that we start at $1$ and never hit $3$.

Could you please have a check on my attempt? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't understand, so I asked a question. What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: My Professor said that there is no stupid question.

Comment: Note that "there are no stupid questions" is better described as a contract between the teacher and the students rather than a statement of fact.  That said, I don't see a reason for downvoting, but your question is arguably unclear, possibly giving reason to vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that probability $1$ means an event is "almost sure", not a sure thing.  While it's possible to never hit state 3, it is exceedingly unlikely.  It is similar to flipping a fair coin and tails never showing up even when flipping the coin indefinitely.